# PCRE(PHP) regex to ECMAScript(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

This PCRE Regex is used to validate JSON String.
Now i want to convert this PCRE to javascript to use it in react validation.

PCRE Regex -

```
/(?(DEFINE)
    (?<json>(?>\s*(?&object)\s*|\s*(?&array)\s*))
    (?<object>(?>\{\s*(?>(?&pair)(?>\s*,\s*(?&pair))*)?\s*\}))
    (?<pair>(?>(?&STRING)\s*:\s*(?&value)))
    (?<array>(?>\[\s*(?>(?&value)(?>\s*,\s*(?&value))*)?\s*\]))
    (?<value>(?>true|false|null|(?&STRING)|(?&NUMBER)|(?&object)|(?&array)))
    (?<STRING>(?>"(?>\\(?>["\\\/bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})|[^"\\\0-\x1F\x7F]+)*"))
(?<NUMBER>(?>-?(?>0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?>\.[0-9]+)?(?>[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?))
)
\A(?&json)\z/
```

I am new to regex so unable to do it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74543717/edit) what exactly isn't working with your RegExp in JavaScript so that no everyone has to figure that out first on their own before being able to answer your question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex to validate a json in js, just use:

```
//let a = '{"a": "adhajshd"}'
let a = '{a: adhajshd}'

try
{
        let j = JSON.parse(a)
        console.log(j)
}
catch(e)
{
                console.error(e)
}
```

first output:

```
{ a: 'adhajshd' }
```

second output:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/iban/scripts/node/a.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
```